# How to get rid of PGAdmin 'Notifications' panel

Tags: pgadmin-4

I pushed some key combination by mistake that made this panel pop up:

[image]

Now I can't find how to make it disappear. The solution is not evident at all, and it is really bothering because it covers a big part of the results panel. I already tried closing the application and nothing, it is still there when I open it again.

**EDIT**

Now things are getting worst. Now I dettached the results panel trying to change its size:

[image]

Can't find how to attach it again.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically click the word `Notifications` and drag the dialog around to snap it where you'd like.  Snap will **not** work if you just click the title bar and drag the dialog around.